# Whats source program type for GnuCobol with embedded Postgres

Tags: postgresql, gnucobol, embedded-sql

Have GnuCobol cobc compiler installed in Ubuntu 
esqlOC installed for SQL pre-processing, Cob-DB2 is working fine. For Cobol with postgres what should be the source program type (like .sqb is for Cob db2)
Presume a new DSN has to be added in data server driver config file with IP and port of Postgres

Comment: What about this project? It seems to implement Embedded SQL in GunCOBOL.
https://bigdanzblog.wordpress.com/2020/10/28/embedded-sql-for-gnucobol-using-ocesql/
https://github.com/opensourcecobol/Open-COBOL-ESQL

Answer (score 0):

There is no PostgreSQL preprocessor for embedded SQL in Cobol.

You should write the code that accesses the database in C and link the compiled C code with your Cobol program.

You can have embedded SQL in C for PostgreSQL using the `ecpg` preprocessor that is included in PostgresSQL.